How big of a walk-in shower is too big?
We are in the early stages of renovating our master bathroom. The floor space is 10'x 12'. It used to be two small bathrooms, one was a half bath accessible from outside. Part of the reason we wanted to redo it was to have a large walk-in shower with shower heads on each side.
We got an architect to draw up plans and she had an 84" by 42" plan for the shower. But now that we've done our demo and are marking off the floors and hanging sheets to see our actual space, it looks crazy big. And we worry it will be cold and drafty in the wintertime. We will have sub floor heat under the main tiles, and I will ask the GC about putting them in the shower as well. We also have a 4'x5' picture window for the back wall of this shower (it faces out into our woods), so going much smaller is going to make it almost all window.
My wife and I both like a hot and steamy shower and will shower together pretty often. Is a 7' by 42" going to be drafty or hard to get warm? Is that "too big" for a walk in shower? There's room for all the fixtures and such, but we're getting to the point that we have to decide. Thanks for your thoughts.

This is all a matter of opinion and in the end it is solely your decision.  To help you to decide think of what enclosure you will have. Is there going to be a glass door? Glass panels?  Is so they will hold in the hot moist air from the showers and keep it warm. If you are open with just maybe some 1/2 walls not so much will be retained.  And that big window begs some questions best not asked here.

How do you plan to get the shower warm? run it for 20 minutes?

Haha, we stayed at an Air B&B that had a giant picture window going out into a wooded area like ours and loved it. The wife in particular. And our house is high up so even if someone was walking through the woods, they might see us from the shoulders up at most. Unless they climbed a tree, there wouldn't be much exposed.

We are looking into a glass shower door like this: https://imgur.com/owe1JrY

For one person, probably much too big.  It depends on how many people your wife will allow in with you.

Giant walk-in showers... the ecological equivalent of a Humvee. For what it's worth, I put in many that size and larger as a builder during the 00s. Body sprays, rain heads, towel warmers, the works. If you have modern insulation it's not an issue.

you can heat the shower walls

a large shower is suitable for washing a dog ... it could be a selling point

TLDR: If you chalked it out and already don't like it, you are right, and should make it smaller.  7 feet is huge.  10x12 is a big bathroom but not vast, and there are other ways to use the space and the budget.

The width should be 40 to 48 inches.  40 is fine, 42 is perfect, 44 is roomy, 48 gets unnecessarily large and your concerns about that are valid.
With two showers the length should be 48 for a very cozy experience, 60 if you want to be able to wash at the same time and don't mind knocking elbows a little, and maybe 72 to 80 if you want more of a locker room experience.
7 feet is excessive. Anything over 48 will feel too big if you are alone.
IMO floor heat in the shower is a waste of money.  There's never budget for EVERYTHING.  The hot water will heat the floor and you won't get much enjoyment from the floor heat, which is expensive.  And, the room thermostat will control the floor temperature in such a way that the shower floor may or may not feel warm, randomly.  Unless it has its own zone ... but your bathroom isn't big enough for that.

Appreciate your thoughts. Part of the reason I considered running heat into the shower itself was our cold winters, and that it might help the floor dry more quickly and reduce moisture and grout cleaning. But going over budget isn't something I want to happen, so every little thing that isn't a useful addition needs to be avoided.

And I appreciate the thoughts on 7' being a bit much. I may go with 6' now. In addition to saving some money, it will open up the rest of the room more.

Build a 42x80 stall out of cardboard or whatever you have.  Go in it with your wife, and go through the motions of pretend shampooing your hair, pretend washing between your toes, etc etc.  Then try 75, and keep making it smaller til you don't like it.

Faster drying might help with reducing mold formation but hopefully you don't have that problem and don't need that solution.   Mostly, grout cleaning is soap scum, calcium and iron.  And faster drying will make no difference.  Might even make it worse!  As for your cold winters .....

The design of a heated floor in a bathroom is very complicated.  The only way to rely on a floor heater to regularly and timely dry your shower floor would be to put it on its own controller that is programmed specifically for that function.  I don't think you can buy such a programmer, it would be a science project.  And like I said, it really doesn't achieve much.  Drying the floor quickly only accelerates mineral deposits.
